# Get the top position of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get the `top` of a div element whose position is relative. So the structure is something similar to :

```
         <div class="head"></div> 
         <div class="main"></div> 
         <div class="foot"></div> 
         div { position : relative; }
```

Now i tried :

```
         $(".foot").css("top") => auto

         $(".foot").offset().top => This gives value but that value is 
                           not matching the current top position of the foot div
```

What i am missing here?

Comment: `$('.foot').offset().top` should give you a value. What exactly is wrong with the value you are getting?

Comment: Copying your stuff over to: http://jsfiddle.net/wqwcA/ - it looks fine, as far as I can tell?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yB3k8/ Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetTop).

[Demo. I make the window automatically scroll to the top of the `div`](http://jsfiddle.net/QtXhU/)

Answer (score 1):

How about [`$('.foot').position().top`](http://api.jquery.com/position/)? this gives you the position relative to the parent DOM element